# What is the minimal code to find the Fourier transform of an image in EmguCV.3.1.0.1?

Tags: c#, winforms, image-processing, emgucv

I want to find the FT of an image, and show its magnitude, and, phase spectrum in EmguCV.3.1.0.1.

I was trying something like the following:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    const string path = @"lenagr.png";
    Image<Bgr, float> image;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        image = new Image<Bgr, float>(path);

        pictureBox1.Image = image.Bitmap;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        Mat dft = new Mat(image.Size, DepthType.Default, 2);
        CvInvoke.Dft(image, dft, DxtType.Forward, image.Rows);

        Mat[] images = dft.Split();

        //Show The Data   
        //Image<Bgr, float> im2 = dft.ToImage<Bgr, float>();
        pictureBox2.Image = images[0].Bitmap;
    }
}
```

This source code freezes the application.

So, What is the absolutely minimal code to find the Fourier transform of an image in EmguCV.3.1.0.1?

**Note:**  [The following source code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7696910/159072) doesn't even compile in  EmguCV.3.1.0.1. And, it looks a job lot.

```
Image<Gray, float> image = new Image<Gray, float>(open.FileName);
IntPtr complexImage = CvInvoke.cvCreateImage(image.Size, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.IPL_DEPTH.IPL_DEPTH_32F, 2);

CvInvoke.cvSetZero(complexImage);  // Initialize all elements to Zero
CvInvoke.cvSetImageCOI(complexImage, 1);
CvInvoke.cvCopy(image, complexImage, IntPtr.Zero);
CvInvoke.cvSetImageCOI(complexImage, 0);

Matrix<float> dft = new Matrix<float>(image.Rows, image.Cols, 2);
CvInvoke.cvDFT(complexImage, dft, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CV_DXT.CV_DXT_FORWARD, 0);

//The Real part of the Fourier Transform
Matrix<float> outReal = new Matrix<float>(image.Size);
//The imaginary part of the Fourier Transform
Matrix<float> outIm = new Matrix<float>(image.Size);
CvInvoke.cvSplit(dft, outReal, outIm, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

//Show The Data       
CvInvoke.cvShowImage("Real", outReal);
CvInvoke.cvShowImage("Imaginary ", outIm);
```

It is not clear what statement is doing what. Also, it mixes up `IntPtr`, `Image<T1, T2>`, `Matrix<T>`, and doesn't make use of `Mat`.

Comment: *This source code freezes the application.* does it mean it crashes or it takes too much time? A Fourier Transform is an easy task. Why dont you write it your self.

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε, `does it mean it crashes or it takes too much time?` --- it takes too much time, and never completes the execution.

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε, `A Fourier Transform is an easy task. Why don't you write it your self.` --- **1.** I need to start learning EmguCV for image processing for which I am not finding any suitable book or tutorial; **2.** I need to learn EmguCV, to be specific. So, writing a new framework is not really an option.

Comment: Have you seen this [Discrete Fourier Transform](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/discrete_fourier_transform/discrete_fourier_transform.html)? You probably can translate it to EmguCV.

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε, theoretically, say, I don't know C++.

Comment: C++ is quite close to C# as the syntax goes. You can understand the basic things. Just see the order of the function calls. These same functions will probably exist in  EmguCV, eg `imread`, `getOptimalDFTSize`,  `copyMakeBorder`, `merge`... etc. That is what i meant *translate*.