# Detect Image Problems

Tags: opencv, emgucv

I really don't know what it is called (distortion or something else) 
But I would like to detect lens camera problems for some different types of images by using emgucv (or opencv)

Any ideas about which algorithms to use would be appreciated

[image: Distortion]

Second image seems to have high noise, but is there any way to understand high noise via opencv?

[image: high noise]

Comment: noise is high frequency, so you can use a high pass filter or compare low pass filtered image with the original image.

Comment: I think in both cases you should be evaluating the SNR (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio)

Comment: Is there any SNR algorithm without reference image?

Comment: Sure, it's usually just the mean gray (or any other channel) value over the standard deviation of the same channel: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio_(imaging)

Comment: You can compute it globally or for sub kernels to understand some measure of noise for the region/image. How you do so will depend on your application; if you have the possibility to evaluate on what would otherwise be a homogeneous part of the image, that would be best. What type of images are you checking; video feeds? single frames?

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood I need to check single frames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very difficult to achieve generically without reference data or a homogeneity sample. However, I have developed a recommendation analyzing the Average SNR ([Signal to Noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio_(imaging))) ratio of the image. The algorithm divides the input image into a specified number of "sub images' based on a specified kernel size in order to evaluate each independently for local SNR. The computed SNRs for each sub image are then mean averaged to provide an **indicator** for the global SNR of the image.

You will need to test this approach exhaustively, however it shows promise on the following three images, producing `AvgSNR`;

**Image #1 - AvgSNR = 0.9**

[image: Image 1]

**Image #2 - AvgSNR = 7.0**

[image: Image 2]

**Image #3 - AvgSNR = 0.6**

[image: Image 3]

**NOTE:** See how the "clean" control image produces a **much higher** `AvgSNR`.

The only variable to consider is the kernel size. I would recommend keeping this at a size that will support will even the smallest of your potential input images. 30 pixels square should likely be appropriate for many images.

I enclose my test code with annotation:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // List of file names to load.
        List<string> fileNames = new List<string>()
        {
            "IifXZ.png",
            "o1z7p.jpg",
            "NdQtj.jpg"
        };

        // For each image
        foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
        {
            // Determine local file path
            string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"TestImages\", fileName);
            // Load the image
            Image<Bgr, byte> inputImage = new Image<Bgr, byte>(path);

            // Compute the AvgSNR with a kernel of 30x30
            Console.WriteLine(ComputeAverageSNR(30, inputImage.Convert<Gray, byte>()));

            // Display the image
            CvInvoke.NamedWindow("Test");
            CvInvoke.Imshow("Test", inputImage);
            while (CvInvoke.WaitKey() != 27) { }
        }

        // Pause for evaluation
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static double ComputeAverageSNR(int kernelSize, Image<Gray, byte> image)
    {
        // Calculate the number of sub-divisions given the kernel size
        int widthSubDivisions, heightSubDivisions;
        widthSubDivisions = (int)Math.Floor((double)image.Width / kernelSize);
        heightSubDivisions = (int)Math.Floor((double)image.Height / kernelSize);
        int totalNumberSubDivisions = widthSubDivisions * heightSubDivisions;
        Rectangle ROI = new Rectangle(0, 0, kernelSize, kernelSize);

        double avgSNR = 0;
        // Foreach sub-divions, calculate the SNR and sum to the avgSNR
        for (int v = 0; v < heightSubDivisions; v++)
        {
            for (int u = 0; u < widthSubDivisions; u++)
            {
                // Iterate the sub-division position
                ROI.Location = new Point(u * kernelSize, v * kernelSize);
                // Calculate the SNR of this sub-division
                avgSNR += ComputeSNR(image.GetSubRect(ROI));
            }
        }

        avgSNR /= totalNumberSubDivisions;

        return avgSNR;
    }

    static double ComputeSNR(Image<Gray, byte> image)
    {
        // Local varibles
        double mean, sigma, snr;

        // Calculate the mean pixel value for the sub-division
        int population = image.Width * image.Height;
        mean = CvInvoke.Sum(image).V0 / population;

        // Calculate the Sigma of the sub-division population
        double sumDeltaSqu = 0;
        for (int v = 0; v < image.Height; v++)
        {
            for (int u = 0; u < image.Width; u++)
            {
                sumDeltaSqu += Math.Pow(image.Data[v, u, 0] - mean, 2);
            }
        }
        sumDeltaSqu /= population;
        sigma = Math.Pow(sumDeltaSqu, 0.5);

        // Calculate and return the SNR value
        snr = sigma == 0 ? mean : mean / sigma;
        return snr;
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** Without a reference, it is not possible to differentiate between natural variance/fidelity and "noise". For example, a highly texture background, or a scene with few homogeneous regions will yield a high `AvgSNR`. This approach will perform best when the evaluated scene consists mostly of plain, mono-color surfaces, such as the server room or shop front. Grass for example would contain a large amount of texture and therefore "noise".

Comment: For some images avg SNR returning infinity. Is this normal? Image has really high noise, but is this expected?

For example: https://snipboard.io/AcD5Ln.jpg

Comment: also is there way  to dynamically decide this 300,300 parameter, as I have sometimes 355X288 images or sometimes really big ones 2560X1980
How can optimize it according to the image size?

Comment: I have replaced the parameter with a kernel size. This will mean you no longer need to determine an appropriate sub-division count dynamically. I also fixed a bug; high SNR is good not bad! Regarding the infinity, technically this can occur on a perfect image of a single color. It was occurring on your test image due to a bug which I've fixed now.

Comment: If you want to link me some repository of test images I can have an experiment, but my feeling is that this approach should answer your question.

Comment: you are great! now I have much better results. but this image is still returning infinity.
https://snipboard.io/MdqPyl.jpg

Comment: Another question is that as you can see there is time and camera name as OSD. Do you thinkg removing them should improve detection considerably? Or is it negligible?

Comment: "Great", I don't think so, haha! Just enthusiastic. I put a final fix to catch the "infinity" happening, however, that last image will produce a very high SNR suggesting it's a "good" image. This is the limitation I advised: Since the image has large homogeneous areas, it could be interrupted as having little noise. Increasing the kernel size to 90 prevents a "sub-image" as been evaluated as near perfect, and again identifies it as being "bad". Optimizing the kernel size will take some testing on your part.

Comment: With regards to the text, since the edges are sharp, it will be evaluated as high frequency, aka "noise". Removing it will be a headache and since it's localized, it won't contribute much to the average. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215039/discussion-between-george-kerwood-and-afgone).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method is to consider evaluating your images in the frequency domain following a Fourier transform. Principally, the noise examples you have provided are images containing unwanted, high frequency content. Conduct FFT and evaluate for images violating a threshold for high frequencies. Here you will from an example of FFT with Emgu: [FFT with Emgu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691601/fourier-transform-of-an-image-in-emgucv)

Comment: how to test if it violates threshold for high frequncies? Any code snippet would be appreciated

Comment: I'm sorry, this isn't something I've previously conducted so it would take me some time to come back to you. I'm curious myself, so watch this space.